# HTMLwebpackPlugin - Is it possible to require partials while in partial?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

Earlier I've been using gulp-nunjucks for templating - **content extends layout and includes partials**. So I've tried to sorta replicate this with `html-webpack-plugin`

***webpack.config.js***

```
const pages = ['home', 'page1'];

const pagesToHTMLPlugin = function(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(page) {
        return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            page: page,
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/_layout.html'),
            filename: page + '.html',
            inject: 'body'
        });
    });
};
let plugins = pagesToHTMLPlugin(pages).concat(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' }));

module.exports = {
   //...
   plugins: plugins
}
```

at ***_layout.html*** i'm successfully requiring partials pages gets rendered with required html files.

```
//...
<body>
    <%= require('html-loader!./partials/header.html') %>
    <%= require('html-loader!./pages/' + htmlWebpackPlugin.options.page + '.html') %>
</body>
```

yet same approach doesn't work if I'm trying to require partial inside already required partial at *_layout.html* - `require('html-loader!./pages/' + htmlWebpackPlugin.options.page + '.html')` .

***/pages/home.html***

```
<%= require('html-loader!./partials/test-partial.html') %>
```

Is there any way require `html-wepback-plugin` partial within another partial? Should I apply some kind of a loader to enable it?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I have the same issue. cheers

Comment: nah. i ended up using webpack for js bundling, and gulp for everything else - server, watching changes, html templating, style preprocessing.

Comment: Hi there I figured this out `{
            test: /\.html$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/components'),
            use: [
              { 
                loader: 'html-loader', 
                options: { 
                  interpolate: true 
                }, 
              }
            ]
          }` and then in your partials within partials `${require('../../components/button/_button.html')}`